# Transparent shadow not appearing in viewer node

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes, transparency, texture-baking, shadows

I am trying to create a transparent shadow using the compositor in blender 2.8, i used a image invert and viewer node to get rid of the white portion of the image, but the changed image wont show up in my viewer node in image editor, is there anything that i'm doing wrong here?[image: Baked shadow with white parts]

[image: Setup in compositor]

[image: Empty viewer node]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.
Right now your compositing nodes will display nothing because there's nothing fed in the input color. So basically you ask Blender to display "nothing" according to an alpha map.

Besides, I'm pretty sure you want to display this shadow on the floor beneath your model. In which case, what you want to do is either use a material on that flood to display shadows where you want and not use compositing at all.

Something like that:
[image: demo]

Compositing is meant to make changes on the rendered picture. May it be color corrections, deformations, ... But it's really on the rendered picture level, not on what will be rendered. Think of it like editing pictures with Photoshop, but using nodes.

Comment: I was trying to make the white part transparent so that i could export the shadow as png and use it in unity, thats why i needed to see it in viewer node without the white part, and save it like that. so basically i dont exactly need to see it in rendered view, i just need to be able save the shadow as png with transparency